# How to query object with contains specific key in array in Graphql

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I have object to query:

```
query demo {
   demo {
     name # string
     words # array of strings
   }
}
```

I am sending this query to API, property `words` is array of strings.

I would like to query all object which contains `hello` in `words` (array of strings) property.

It is possible on client side using for example `@include` ?

And how?

Comment: It either needs to be setup server-side to filter results for a word (either hard-coded there or by parameter, in which you need to make a different query), or you can make the general query you have and filter the results

Answer (score 0):

The `@skip` and `@include` directives are used to explicitly skip or include a particular field based on the provided `if` argument. They are normally used in conjunction with variables, so that the same document can be used to effectively generate queries with different selection sets (sets of fields) based on the provided variable.

For example, you can write a single query like this

```
query demo($includeName: Boolean!) {
   demo {
     name @include(if: $includeName)
     words
   }
}
```

and just pass in a different value for `includeName` instead of writing two separate queries:

```
query demoWithName {
   demo {
     name
     words
   }
}

query demoWithoutName {
   demo {
     words
   }
}
```

GraphQL provides built-in mechanism for specifying which fields to return like fragments and the `@skip` and `@include` directives. It does not, however, have any built-in mechanism for filtering (or, for that matter, sorting, pagination, etc.). The server has to implement a way to filter fields by adding the appropriate arguments to fields and changing the field resolution logic to account for the values of those arguments.